# How to update Text() in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-text

How can I update a Text() using a RaisedButton?

> I need to run it without setState

```
RaisedButton(
  child: Text('Press Me To update Text !'),
  onPressed: (){
    changetext = 'it has been changed';
  },
)
```

Thanks for helping me :)

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you have to be inside a `StatefulWidget`, so you can call `setState`.
If you change a variable without calling `setState` you won't see the change in the UI.

You'll have to store the text in a variable

```
String _text = 'Press Me To update Text !';
```

And update it like this;

```
RaisedButton(
   onPressed: () {
      setState(() {
        _text = 'The text is updated';
      });
   },
   child: Text(_text),
)
```

Here's the [whole app](https://gist.github.com/doppelledev/2a78883bffde0a160ccf14f9ee2051e5), you can run it yourself.

Comment: i need to run it without setState

Comment: "i need to run it without setState".  Please elaborate.  If you reply "I need to do it without using $BEST_SOLUTION" like that... we have to wonder what the constraint is that keeps you from using $BEST_SOLUTION.

Comment: @RandalSchwartz don't be toxic man, just try to use in wrapped by Builder or StatefulBuiler

Comment: I meant what I said.  There's a universe of solutions out there.  Once you rule out the best solution, there are usually many "second best" solutions, so it's important when answering to understand why the best is ruled out.  Not trying to be "toxic". Just giving the best service in a slow-chat environment.